# How does this loop work on Es5/Es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

So, trying to learn a bit about ES6, I came over this link, http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedVariables

```
// ES6

let callbacks = []
for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    callbacks[i] = function () { return i * 2 }
}
callbacks[0]() === 0
callbacks[1]() === 2
callbacks[2]() === 4

// ES5

var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        callbacks[i] = function() { return i * 2; };
    })(i);
}
callbacks[0]() === 0;
callbacks[1]() === 2;
callbacks[2]() === 4;
```

May I know why in ES5 Method we are using an immediate function to return the i*2 value?

But in ES6, just assigning the value in loop works?

Basically,

1. Want to Know why this difference occurs?
2. How does that loop is getting executed?
3. I find the difference is due to "block scope (let) & global scope (var)", but want to know more about the execution/runtime point?
4. So we don't want to use immediate function for saving the current state of variable in ES6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - "let" keyword vs "var" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword)

Comment: @TaoP.R. If it's duplicated, please explain how that loop works?

Comment: see also [Explanation of `let` and block scoping with for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30900289/1048572) (not sure if duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, the difference is between using `let` which creates a block-scoped variable vs using `var` which creates an *execution context* scoped variable - not just global, but the executing function's scope.

```
// ES6
var callbacks = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    // A new LexicalEnvironment is established here, where i only survives
    // the duration of this 'for' statement
    // So we can safely say that when function() is called, `i` will have
    // the value we assign to it here
    callbacks[i] = function () { return i * 2 }
}
```

However, in ES5...

```
// LexicalEnvironment is established here and `i` is declared
var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    callbacks[i] = function() { return i * 2; };
}
// `i` is still available now and its value is currently 2
// So when you execute `callbacks[2]()` the LexicalEnvironment where `i` was set
// is the one where i === 3
callbacks[0]() // 6
callbacks[1]() // 6
callbacks[2]() // 6
```

Now, using an IIFE in ES5...

```
var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    // Much like using let, by declaring an IIFE here, we are telling the engine
    // to create a new LexicalEnvironment to store the current value of i
    (function (i) {
        callbacks[i] = function() { return i * 2; };
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Does Ecmascript6 Support hoisting?

Comment: @Sathish Yes. As far as hoisting goes, the same rules go for `let` as go for `var` except you won't be able access the declared `let` variable outside of it's block scope