# SyntaxError: missing = in const declaration Firefox 50

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6, constants

I have a loop like the following:

```
const bar = {a: 1, b: 2}
for (const k in bar) { //Throws in Firefox but not Chrome 54
    console.log(k)
}
```

Is this a bug? Or maybe a gray area in the spec?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be a bug in Firefox. The [spec allows the use of `const`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-iteration-statements):

```
IterationStatement:
    for(ForDeclaration in Expression) Statement

ForDeclaration:
    LetOrConst ForBinding

ForBinding:
    BindingIdentifier
    BindingPattern
```

(truncated and simplified)

It seems Firefox is incorrectly interpreting *ForDeclaration* as a [*LexicalBinding*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-static-semantics-early-errors).

Related: [ECMAScript 2015: const in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31987465/218196)

This seems like the bug report for this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1101653 .

---

Proper `let` and `const` is coming to Firefox: https://twitter.com/evilpies/status/768881995912994816

Comment: Huh, Firefox is making the same mistake I made when reading the spec. Didn't think to check for loops for special behavior.