# Inconsistent scope rules of variables in for, for-in and for-of loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, scope, for-in-loop

So I noticed that I have to use `let` inside a `for` loop, and cannot use `const`. However, I found that I can use `const` inside the `for-in` and `for-of` constructs (code below). Intuitively I can rationalize that this is because the `for` loop is implemented differently/is more primitive, whereas the other constructs desugar into for loops where the iterating variable is assigned at the top of the for loop.

```
// Doesn't work
for (const i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

// Works
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

// Works
const object2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (const v of object2) {
  console.log(v);
}

// Works
const object3 = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
};
for (const v in object3) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

The only thing I could find on Mozilla MDN about this was on the [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop page:

> This expression may optionally declare new variables with the var
>   keyword. These variables are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in
>   the same scope the for loop is in. The result of this expression is
>   discarded.

Which also seems wrong, because if we use a `let` for `i` then `i` is no longer in scope after the `for` loop (which is consistent with other languages)

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
// Doesn't work as expected
console.log(i);
```

My question is whether this behaviour is expected and defined in the spec somewhere? MDN doesn't say much about this.

Comment: Regarding "*…if we use a let for i…*", that is different to the MDN code which uses *var*, not *let*.

Comment: @robG ahh true, the second sentence of that quote is in reference to the first sentence. I stand corrected.

Comment: See also [ES6 internals of const in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45211241/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I noticed that I have to use let inside a for loop, and cannot use const.

No. You can use a `const` declaration in a `for` loop just fine. The problem just is that `const` declares a constant binding, so an increment `i++` doesn't work on `const i` (it should throw an exception, make sure you're in strict mode).

An example of how to use `const`:

```
for (const o = {index: 0, value: null}; o.index < arr.length; o.index++) {
    o.value = arr[o.index];
    doSomething(o);
}
```

Or one where it makes more sense:

```
for (const iterator = makeIterator(); !iterator.isDone(); iterator.next())
    doSomething(iterator.getCurrent());
}
```

> Intuitively I can rationalize that this is because the for loop is implemented differently/is more primitive, whereas the other constructs desugar into for loops where the iterating variable is assigned at the top of the for loop.

Yes. In a `for` loop, you need to take care of updating the iteration variables yourself.

- ```
  for ([var] init; condition; update) {
      body
  }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  [var] init;
  while (condition) {
      body;
      update;
  }
  ```
- ```
  for (const init; condition; update) {
      body
  }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  {
      const init;
      while (condition) {
          body;
          update;
      }
  }
  ```
- ```
  for (let init; condition; update) {
      body
  }
  ```

  becomes [something more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900289/1048572)

In `for … in` and `for … of` loops, you just declare an assignment target expression for the produced value.

- ```
  for ([var]/let/const target of iterable) {
      body
  }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  {
      const _iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
      let _result;
      while (!(_result = _iterator.next()).done) {
          [var]/let/const target = _result.value;
          body;
      }
  }
  ```
- `for (… in enumerable)` is just the same as `for (… of Reflect.enumerate(enumerable))`.

> The only thing I could find on Mozilla MDN about this was on the `for` loop page, which also seems wrong.

Yes, looks like that section hasn't yet been updated for ES6.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is indeed expected behavior.

`const` defines a variable which, as the name suggested, stays constant. That means the value of a const cannot change.

Now what you do in your `for` loop is incrementing "i", which was defined as a constant.

```
for (const i = 0; i < 3; i++ /* <- this doesn't work */ ) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

with `for .. in` or `for .. of` however, you just bind the variable.

In other words: With `for .. in/off`, the variable gets assigned once before execution of the loop and not on every iteration. Therefore `const` can indeed be used.

As for the reference:

> ForDeclaration : LetOrConst ForBinding

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-static-semantics-boundnames

Answer (score 2):

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-static-semantics-boundnames)

> ForDeclaration : LetOrConst ForBinding

`let` and `const` is allowed in **for-in** and **for-of** statements.

Also, as per **run-time semantics** mentioned in [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-bindinginstantiation)

> For each element name of the BoundNames of ForBinding do

This expression  `for (const v in object3) {` is **executed for each iteration and give a new binding**.

However, with **simple for-loop** - `for (const i = 0; i < 3; i++) {`, *`const i` is only executed once* and **hence it doesn't allow you to re-assign a value to it**.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question has been answered by @NullDev, so I'm going to the second:

> This expression may optionally declare new variables with the var
>   keyword. These variables are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in
>   the same scope the for loop is in. The result of this expression is
>   discarded.

"These variables are not local to the loop" means the counter created by `var` keyword. If you use `let` then the scope of the counter is only in that for loop. This is another expected behavior since `var` has the wideless scope. And yes, the documentation is a little bit ambiguous.