# Why `const` value changed inside of `for...in` and `for...of` loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

> [Constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a `constant` cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be `redeclared`.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) ***The value of a `constant` cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be `redeclared`***, so inside of `for...in` and `for...of` how is working?

```js
const data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

//Here const key is changed
for (const key in data) {
  console.log('key ',key);
}

//Here const value is changed
for (const value of data) {
  console.log('value ',value);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [scope rules of variables in for, for-in and for-of loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49573227/1048572)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every iteration of a loop has its own block scope.

```
 for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
```

That creates 10 seperate scopes, thats why it logs 10 different numbers. Therefore you can also declare constants in these different scopes.

Comment: JavaScript `const` is the least constant `const` of any language I've seen that uses a term like that.  It's not a compile-time constant like in C# or C++.

Comment: @james yes, js is an interpreted language.

Comment: @Jonas That's not really an argument; even JS has a compilation step, and even without a compilation step constants *could* be immutable.

Comment: @deceze i think it is. Javascript is very dynamic in comparison to C++ / C# and thats because it is interpreted. A compiled language can't be that dynamic (without much overhead)

Comment: PHP demonstrates that it's possible to be interpreted and have constant constants. As I'm sure other languages do too. These attributes are unrelated.

Answer (score 5):

The first three words of the material you quoted explains.

> Constants are block-scoped

Each time you go around the `for` loop, you go to the top of a clean block. The first thing you do to it is to create a constant inside it.

Answer (score 4):

In `for-of-loop` those constans are being declared for every iteration (in independent scopes), whereas in a `for-loop` you're re-using the variable, so you won't be able to re-assign values after its declaration.

Example with `for-loop`

```js
const data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

for (const i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log('value ',data[i]);
}
```