# Javascript declaring a variable inside the initialization step

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am watching a video about C programming, and the instructor has an example for loop that is written as such:

```c
for(int i=0, n=strlen(c); i<n; i++)
```

In Javascript can we declare n in the same way as well? I'm trying to not set "i

Edit:

Thank you for the replys. Sounds like I can't do the code from above, but instead I would have to split it up into 2 separate line items like so:

`const n = strlen(c);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`

Comment: Yes, [in a similar way in the same place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement), but no, of course you cannot use `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> In Javascript can we declare n in the same way as well?

Yes. You can use either `var` or `let` there, and it makes a big difference: Inside the loop's block, if you use `var`, all loop iterations share a *single* variable. If you use `let`, each loop iteration gets its **own** variable. This only matters if you create closures within the loop.

Example of the difference:

```js
for (var varvar = 0; varvar < 3; ++varvar) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`varvar = ${varvar}`);
    }, 10);
}

for (let letvar = 0; letvar < 3; ++letvar) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`letvar = ${letvar}`);
    }, 20);
}
```

(And if you use `var`, the variable exists throughout the function [or global scope, if you're doing this at global scope]. With `let`, it's confined to the `for` loop.)

Comment: Don't forget about [`const` declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31987465/1048572), although of course they're only useful if you don't initialise an immutable value and use that in your condition.

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah. Not applicable to `for` loops, but very useful in other kinds of loops (`for-of`, `for-in`, `while`, ...).

Comment: `for (const iterator = …; iterator.hasNext(); iterator.advance()) { … }`

Comment: @Bergi - I suppose, if you don't try to modify the control variable in the increment.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i = 0; i < c.length; i ++)
```

Comment: I'm trying to not have javascript calculate c.length everytime the forloop iterates. With this way it has to use memory everytime it iterates. I'm guessing I'd have to declare n before my for loop, and use it as the condition statement.

Comment: Then you can do like 
`const length = c.length
for(let i =0; i < length; I ++)`