# Understanding closure,Creating different scope for each iteration

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to understand closures in Javascript. I came across below three examples.

Expample 1:

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("i :" + i)
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

And the output is as expected as it prints "i : 11" to the console 11 times because only one scope is created for entire loop that is global scope.To have different scope in each iteration I used IIFE(Immediately invoked function expression) please see the below code snippet.
example: 2

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("i : " + i)
    }, i * 1000)
  })(i);
}
```

It prints from "i:0" to "i:10" as expected because different scope is created for each iteration.
I'm not able to understand what exactly is happening in the below code snippet.
example :3

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("i :" + i)
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

It prints from "i:0" to "i:10".
1 .I'm not able to understand why the output is not as same as first example i.e print "1:11" 11 times?
2 . Is different scope is being created for each iteration if I use block scope?
3 . If different scope is being created, then how is it different from example-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `let` operates with block scope (`var` does not). This means that it is like declaring a local variable within the block of your code making up the for statement.

For example you can do this:

```
if (blockCount === 3) {
  let x = 1;
  // do something with x
} else {
  let x = 2:
  // do something with x
}

console.log(x);  // undefined since no longer in scope
```

This will work as written. If you try to access `x` outside the `if` statement it would be undefined.

See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you call a `setTimeout()` that prints the variable `i` after a certain time. By the time the `setTimeout()` callbacks fire, the loop has finished and `i` possesses the last iteration value (11). All the callbacks print that variable.

In the second example, you use an immediately invoked function expression ([IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)). This is a function that is defined *and* called immediately, with the argument `i` passed to it.
When you pass an argument to a function, it is like a new local variable was declared. For example:

```js
var foo = 5;

function myLog(foo) {
  console.log(foo);
}

myLog("not 5"); // logs "not 5" instead of 5
```

This means that the argument `i` of the immediately invoked function is different from the `i` used in the loop, but has the same value, because you pass it at the current iteration of the loop.
With this approach, you create 12 different `i` variables. One for the loop, and 11 others for the IIFEs, which the `setTimeout()` callbacks inside of use.

In the third example, a similar thing happens. `let` declares a block scope local variable. When the loop runs, it's like 11 different variables were created and each `setTimeout()` callback references the variable created in its own local scope. This is more thoroughly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900289/3130281).