# Let in Javascript. Confusion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am really confused about this code

```html
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box-value');

for(let i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
    box[i].onclick = function(){
        console.log(i);
    }
    console.log("End loop. i:" + i);
}

let i = 0;
box[i].onclick = function(){
    console.log(i);
}
i = 9;

box[0].onclick();
```

[image]

In the first block, i is 0

[image]

But in the second block, i is 9.

I really don't understand why?

Comment: http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html#let-in-loop-heads

Comment: @trincot I don't think that duplicate applies here

Comment: What part don't you understand? What logs would you have expected instead?

Comment: @Bergi The question isn't the same but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/1848654) also covers `let` in `for` loops.

Comment: @Bergi, I have anyway removed the duplicate... just in case the use of `let` and block scope deserves a separate answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Because your first `i` is in a *block* and [doesn't get changed afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612/1048572), while your second `i` (is not in a block) and does get set to `9` before the click handler is run. You can emulate the behaviour from the loop by doing

```
{
    let i = 0; // one variable that stays constant
    box[i].onclick = function(){
        console.log(i);
    };
}
let i = 9; // a different variable
```

and you can also emulate the altering behaviour of the assignment by putting the scope around the loop:

```
let i = 0;
for(; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(i);
    };
    console.log("End loop. i:" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `i` declared with `let` in the `for` loop won't exist after the loop ends. The second `i` is separate and you setting that to 9, that's why the value of the second `i` is 9.

[`let` statement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)