# ECMAScript 5 'for' loop, with 'i' overwritten, vs. ECMAScript 6 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was interviewed for a JavaScript frontend developer position. I failed because I didn't know a few advanced questions. Please help me to understand at least this one.

My problem was on ECMAScript 6 knowledge, not the for loop in ECMAScript 5 or the closure. I didn't understand what is doing `for/of` or who is doing the magic in this ECMAScript 6 code to not overwrite the `i`.

The question was like:

> To display numbers from 1 to 5 in the for loop, every time we click on a button, we have to wrap the console in a closure, to have the right output, so the `i` variable will not be overwritten if we use this closure.
>
> In ECMAScript 6, in a `for` loop we only have the callback function, and `i` is not overwritten. Why?
>
> ```
> // ECMAScript 5
> for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
>   var btn = document.createElement('button');
>   btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button ' + i));
>   btn.addEventListener('click',
>     function(x) {
>       return function() {
>         console.log(x);
>       };
>     }(i)
>   );
>   document.body.appendChild(btn);
> }
>
> // ECMAScript 6
> const ps = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p'));
>
> for (const [i, paragraph] of ps.entries()) {
>   paragraph.addEventListener('click', function() {
>     return console.log(`${i+1}: ${this.textContent}`);
>   });
>  }
> ```

Comment: Short answer is, because `var` is function scoped, meaning **only one `i`** is available in the closure of all event handlers, but `let` and `const` are block scoped, meaning there is **a unique `i`** available in the closure of each event handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @nem you said "but let and const are block scoped, meaning there is a unique i available in the closure of each event handlers" in es6 for of I don't see any closure

Comment: in both examples, the anonymous function passed as the click handler callback has `i` available in its closure.

Comment: Try using `var` instead of `const` in the `for..of`. The output will always show  `total amount of paragraps: text content for specific paragraph`

Comment: Oo, I can see clearly  now :). I thought that for of does the whole job protecting i, but it's all about of const and let :). Thank you.

Comment: Nit: Their explanation of the ES5 solution is not quite correct. The solution to the loop problem is not the fact that a closure is used but that a *function is called* to create a new scope. Whether or not *that* function is a closure is irrelevant.

Comment: It should read "we need to wrap the closure in an IIFE to create the scope", and the ES6 explanation would be that the closure is in the scope created by the block.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is just a matter of scope. It has nothing to do with the `for...of` loop...

Take a look at these scenarios:

### `var` is global

```js
// "i" is global
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}

console.log(i);
```

### `var` is still global

```js
// "i" is global
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}

console.log(i);
```

### `let` is local

```js
// "i" is local
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}

console.log(i); // ReferenceError
```

### `let` is global

```js
// "i" is global
let i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}

console.log(i);
```

Comment: I see now that is not about for of loop. Their question was very very tricky.

Comment: From what I know, this is a common question in JavaScript interviews... ;)

Comment: I did't know until now. I aspect it to ask me how you define vars in es6, but not putting this complicated code for just a simple basic knowledge about how you define variables :)

Comment: Notice that "let is local" is [a bit more complicated in loops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30900289/1048572), though

Comment: @Bergi: It is true, but I wanted to keep this answer simple. This is purposely not an in-depth answer and Dr. Axel Rauschmayer explains this better than I could: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html#sec_let-const-loop-heads