# Were variables declared in the initialiser expression of for loops always lexically inside the body

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, language-lawyer

When `let` is used in the initialiser expression of a traditional `for` loop, it is scoped to the block of the for loop.

The spec says:

> `let` and `const` declarations define variables that are scoped to the
>   running execution context's `LexicalEnvironment`.

Does that mean that the point of declaration of `i` is (and even in ES5 was(?)) *lexically* (semantically I know using `var` it would be hoisted) **inside** the block comprising the body of the `for` loop (because naively it looks like it is *outside* it).

Or does it mean that this is a new feature of `let` and/or the `for` loop to give it the semantics of being lexically inside the loop body?

To be clear: I know that the visibility semantics are new (i.e. block scoping for `let` vs function scooping for `var`). I am interested in whether the lexical position of definition has always been taken to be inside the body of the loop.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // the body of the loop....
}
```

Comment: "*Does that mean that the point of declaration of `i` is lexically inside the block comprising the body of the for loop?*" - No, what makes you think that?

Comment: Related: [The semantics of `let` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612/1048572)

Comment: Shouldn't this post be tagged with [tag:language-lawyer]?

Comment: @Bergi I know this is basic stuff, but I just assumed I understood how it worked. Then I thought about it... Computers are hard

Comment: @Bergi - intuitively it seemed that the semantic difference for `let` and `var` in a for loop was *more* than just the hoisting aspect. I was grasping at what that additional difference was. I think your linked answer tells me...

Comment: @Ben I think the designers had the elimination of the [closures-within-for-loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/6445533) in mind, amongst other things.

Comment: That prompted the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, think of it like an imaginary wrapper block with all the `for`-declared variables aliased within it. Kind of like this:

```
// Original
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }

// Equivalent
{
    let _i;
    for (_i = 0; _i < 10; _i++) {
        let i = _i;
        ...
        _i = i;
    }
}
```

It works by creating a new scope within the `for` to alias the variables, and then effectively updating the aliases at the end of each block.

(Of course, engines implement it differently than this, but that's when you get into compiler theory and the difference between observable semantics and actual implementation.)

Comment: In ES2015 is a `var` declaration in the initialiser expression taken to have a **lexical** point of declaration inside or outside of the for-loop body block?

Comment: `var` is hoisted to the top of the function as it always has. Nothing has changed in that regard.

Comment: the binding-per-iteration feature is not applicable to `const` with traditional for loops. The hoisting behavior of `let`, `const` *is* the same per your answer, however. The binding-per-iteration behavior was the missing piece of my understanding.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is definitely not right, each iteration of the loop absolutely gets its own `i` binding.

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry for the misstep. (I sometimes get that mixed up myself. :-\ )

Comment: I've also CW'd it, so it can be better improved.