# Why JavaScript const works well with for in loop

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, for-in-loop

Why JavaScript `const` works same as `let` in `for in` loop? `const` is using to declare constants in EC6. Then why the `const num` value getting updated in each iteration of the `for in`?

**For in with let**

```
for (let num in nums) {
    console.log(num); // works well, as usual
}
```

**For in with const**

```
for (const num in nums) {
    console.log(num); // why const value getting replaced
}
```

Comment: is only read you havent changeit, so no error only  iteration

Comment: Because `const` is block scoped to your `for...in` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why JavaScript const works same as let in for in loop?

By definition, `const` is block scoped like `let`.

> Then why the const num value getting updated in each iteration of the for in?

It isn't. Since it is block scoped, each time you go around the loop the old constant drops out of scope and you create a new one.

Answer (score 8):

> Why the `const num` value getting updated in each iteration of the `for in`?

It isn't getting updated. [Similar to `let`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612/1048572), it is scoped to the loop block and creates a new `const` variable on every iteration, initialised with the respective property key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (not sure) is for the scope in which it's declared. It seems you are declaring the constant in the scope of the for statement, so it gets removed and redeclared every new iteration. So each time it has a different value.

It's a guess, not sure...