# Loops and closures. For and Var

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, var, let

I found many topics explaining this problem, on how I can fix the following code by using var, like this one
http://conceptf1.blogspot.com/2013/11/javascript-closures.html or this one [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

But I really can't understand why it is not working when using var and working when using let.

```
var funcs = [];        
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {        //  let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function() {            //  and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i);   //  each should log its value.
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                        //  and now let's run each one to see
}
// outputs 3 3 3
```

I really have no clue...

Comment: Do you mean "*not working when using var and working when using let*"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of \`let\` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899612/explanation-of-let-and-block-scoping-with-for-loops)

Comment: I checked all the other duplicates and I couldn't understand them, only the answer below helped me to understand this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ES6's let` is block scope that means it has it's own scope inside `{}` like many other traditional languages. But in contrast `var` is a global variable in your code.

In first `for` loop, `function` is just assigned to `func[i]` 3 times  with final value 3 but not executed. If you execute the function inside first `loop`, you will get the expected output though like:

```js
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
  funcs[i](); // execution of func
}
```

So, the important thing is in which context your function is executing.

Now, by the time `funcs[j]()` is executed for the first time in your code, `i`'s value is already `3`. If you want to log incremented value, you have to pass that as an argument like the following:

```js
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function(j) {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + j); // each should log its value.
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j](j);                      // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

Comment: I think I start to understand it now. So this line of code -> console.log("My value: " + i); will use the global i (3) value when using var? And if I use let, each iteration will maintain different i value for the function definition?

Comment: So basically, 3 iterations will "make" 3 block scopes?

Comment: I think that is the best explanation I have found so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because `var` is function-scoped (that is, having the scope of the surrounding function), whereas `let` & `const` are block-scoped - thus having their own values inside each block (be it `if`- or `else`-block or each iteration of the loop as in your case). Block-scoped variables are not defined outside the block. Function-scoped variables stay until the end of the function.

Your `i` variable is function-scoped, which means once your loop is completed, it's still present outside the first loop & has a value of `3`. So once you call your array function, it takes `i` from the upper scope (which is `3`) & outputs it. If you used `let`, for example, you'd  get a fresh binding for each iteration & your `i`'s value would keep the initial declaration value.

Edit:
So in order to output sequential values, you need to replace `var` with `let`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i] = function() {
    // now `i` is bound to the scope & keeps its initial value
    console.log("My value: " + i); 
  };
}
```

Comment: could you add rewritten code to my answer, so I can easily understand what is going on? Is it something like: var i = 0; for (i; i < 3; i++) ? Could you write when i scope start and finish when using var and let?

Comment: I know how to make it work, all other posts and topics gave me an answer, but I dont really see why the initial solution with var is not working... Maybe there exist some other code example that I can understand?

Comment: @Marek, if your question is "*but I dont really see why the initial solution with var is not working*" then you should say so, and you should not iclude `let` in there because that confuses by opening another questions, I invite you to edit your post to reflect what you really wonder about

Answer (score 0):

Unlike to `let`, `var` is hoisted outside the loop scope. In fact, your `i` variable will always equals to the last iteration (which in your example is 3). `let` doesn’t have this problem cause it is not hoisted.