# What is the scope of 'let' keyword in ES6 (Please see the code snippets below)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Question title seems straight forward but that's not what I am asking. Please try following examples

```js
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
 //console.log(i);
 let i=5 
 console.log(i);
}
```

This example works and my question is how is it possible to declare another variable with same identifier inside for loop.

I am really confused, what is going on??

Comment: It seems that it's the *opposite* of "never ending" - it terminates after a single iteration.

Comment: Wouldn't the opposite be "never starting"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Comment: @DaveNewton, now it is never ending (changed the value to 2), and I now know why it is never ending, basically it's never ending loop now.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler no it not duplicate, my question is based on the code snippets I posted.

Comment: Questions can be duplicates of each other even if the code is different.

Answer (score 5):

For the semantics of `let` in `for` loops, see [Explanation of `let` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612/1048572).

> How is it possible to declare another variable with same identifier inside `for` loop?

It's because your `for` loop has a *block statement* as its body, and in there you can declare your own block-scoped variables, shadowing the ones from parent scopes.

Comment: Yes, if what you said is true, it totally makes sense. Is there any reference to what you said (MDN??) where I can explore more?

Comment: @Raaz I don't know any good references to link, sorry. My knowledge comes directly from the spec, which I cannot recommend to read. What else would you like to know?

Answer (score 0):

In the following example you set the value of `i` to `5` so the loop ends coz that's the condition for the loop `i<5`. So condition is false for the loop to run again

```js
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
 //console.log(i);
 i=5 
 console.log(i);
}
```

And in your firs example, loop continues coz `let i =5` is considered a separate variable in the for loop scope

Comment: Actually, I modified the question little bit, I changed it to 2 (something smaller than 5) and yes, it makes sense now the loop runs forever. I got that part. But what about my first question? How is it possible to declare a variable with same identifier within the scope?

Comment: and that's causing this page to crash. :/

Comment: "considered a separate variable??" this does not makes sense to me. How two variables with same identifier considered different in same scope?? That brings back the question what is the actual scope of let??

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will remove all your doubt It is all about `scope`, You can not re-define same variable in same `scope` but you can define in nested `scope`

Same thing happening in your code `for` has own scope and inside `for` means

```
for { //inside this } is  nested scope of `for`.
```

```js
{
    let a = "a";
    console.log(a);
    {
        let a = "b";
        console.log(a);
    }
    console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant, yes, if it is nested block it's a simple thing to understand, can you point me to the reference or documentation where this behavior of for's nested scope is explained?

Comment: @Raaz http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-block-level-scoping-let-const/ this link contains detail explanation about `var`, `let ` and `const`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of people are talking around the real point of confusion here...

Ok, so when you say

```
// scope A
for(let i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    //scope B
}
```

we know `i` is *not* declared in Scope A.  (That's one of the big problems `let` solves.)  So it seems it must be declared in Scope B.  But what about this case?

```
// scope A
for(let i = 0; i<5; i++) console.log(i);
```

The for loop *still* has to have its own scope, in order to keep `i` from being in Scope A.  And we can demonstrate this.

```
let i = 37;
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) console.log(i);

console.log(i); // prints 37
```

Now if the `for` statement *already* has a scope even though it has no braces, then what happens when we replace `console.log(i)` with a block statement?  Well, that block statement gets its own scope.  So really we have

```
// Scope A
for( //scope B is actually here
     let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Scope C
}
```