# how to get array value in ajax success method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, scope

I want to redirect to the fastest URL after `ajax` called all the URLs, but when I alert the value, I get `undefined`:

```
var servers = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: servers[i],
    data: {},
    cache: false,
    success: function(output) { 
      // window.location.href = servers[i]
      alert(servers[i]);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Try `let i` instead of `var i` (the reason this fails is that `i` is increased a final time thanks to the `i++` right before the loop ends, is now `3` and `servers[3]` is `undefined`)

Comment: @ChrisG i tested, it works, please post your answer

Comment: Actually, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900289/11908502) is the more exact answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.race` instead of iteration. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

```
const servers = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
const requests = servers.map(server => $.ajax({...}));

Promise.race(requests)
    .then(/* handle the fastest request */)
    .catch(/* catch error here */)
```