# var single binding v/s let multiple bindings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the example below, I have heard that `var` creates single binding for the variable, while `let` creates a new binding for each iteration. I wanted to understand in-depth what exactly does it mean and how it works internally?

```js
//var
const arr = [];

for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
  arr.push(function(){
    return i;
  })
}

console.log(arr.map(function(x){
  return x();
}));
```

```js
//let
const arr = [];

for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
  arr.push(function(){
    return i;
  })
}

console.log(arr.map(function(x){
  return x();
}))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. It works exactly as you described and the two examples showcase it accurately. You can also see [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1451009) and [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486)

Comment: While I am aware of the output, I wanted to understand how it works internally between var and let.

Comment: "how it works internally" is described in the [ECMA specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations). Though each browsers exact implementation will differ. They should all follow these rules.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900289/218196 explains what happens internally.

Answer (score 2):

One of the key difference between `let` and `var` is:

> Variables declared with `var` or created by function declarations in non-strict mode do not have block scope. Variables introduced within a block are scoped to the containing function or script, and the effects of setting them persist beyond the block itself. In other words, block statements do not introduce a scope.

**Explanation:**

I will try to explain in simple words:

"*Blocks are scoped to containing function or script*" or *block statements do not introduce a scope*, means anything like below (which is a "block"):

```
{
  StatementList
}
```

doesn't create its own scope (Block can be created by simply wrapping statements into curly braces).

Okay, lets see an example:

```
function foo()
{
    var x = 1;
    {
      var x = 2;
    }
    console.log(x);
}
```

> prints 2.

Function `foo` has its own scope, but block doesn't. Hence the value changed or new declaration inside block statement(the curly braces outside of line `var x = 2` creates new block) is persisted outside the block, i.e. in console statement.

However if we declare a variable `x` again outside the function `foo` it will be entirely different and will have its own scope.
suppose we have another function in same script block (or same module/file):

```
function xyz()
{
    var x = 3;
    console.log(x);
}
```

> prints 3

What does this mean?, "It means **functions create their own scope**". So both `x` one inside `foo` and other inside `xyz` are entirely different. Changing one would have effect only inside its own function scope.

Now `let`

**What `var` is for two different functions, `let` is for two different blocks**. So every block creates its own scope for `let`.

So if I changed my function `foo` to:

```
function foo()
{
    let x = 1;
    {
      let x = 2;
    }
    console.log(x);
}
```

> prints 1

This means the block inside function has its own scope, and the `var x` is entirely different from the one outside.

**What happens with loop?**

It creates different block for each iteration, so loop can be expanded like below:

```
 /*---------Block 1------------*/
  {
    let i = 0; 
    //... other loop statments
    arr.push(function(){
        return i;
      });
   }
/*----------Block 2-----------*/
    {
    let i = 1; 
    //...
    arr.push(function(){
        return i;
      })
    }
/*--------- Block 3------------*/
    {
    let i = 2; 
    //... 
    arr.push(function(){
        return i;
      })
    }
```

Now we see, all three `let` are having their own scope which is introduced by the pair of curly braces we have for each iteration of loop, but in case of `var` it will be single scope irrespective of how many blocks we create.
As variable `i` is not immediately used in block but its used inside a function which creates its own scope and will take the value from its outer scope, in case of `var` outer scope is only one (which would have final value of `i` i.e. 3) but in case `let` there are 3 outer scope, hence each will have its own value.

**Reference**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block
For the other differences between `var` and `let`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/1421196

Comment: This highlights one of the differences in `var` vs `let` but misses others, e.g. hoisting see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/542251

Comment: Agree, this is only about scoping, not to explain all difference of let and var. I changed wording accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Awesome explanation...Only one question...When you say "As variable i is not immediately used in block", do you mean that the actual function call is afterwards?

Comment: You can say so, but its not entirely correct. So i is not used in the same context in which loop is executed, the context where i is used is executed once the full loop is done. if we use setTimeout with 0 timeout value in loop, the same thing will happen.