# Not able to understand the output of this for loop in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout, var, let

I have understood why the output of this code should be `3 3 3`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

I am not able to understand, though, why the output of this code is `0 1 2`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

I want more clarity with the output of the second `for` loop.

Comment: apparently I'm not allowed to vote to close this as a duplicate while there's a bounty - but really everything about this is already covered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of `let` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612/1048572)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation of \`let\` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899612/explanation-of-let-and-block-scoping-with-for-loops)

Answer (score 18):

There is a difference of the **scope** with `let` and `var`, which causes them to behave differently.

Here is a quote from other [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) about the differences between `var` and `let`.

> The main difference is scoping rules. Variables declared by `var` keyword are scoped to the immediate function body (hence the function scope) while `let` variables are scoped to the immediate enclosing block denoted by `{ }` (hence the block scope).

So, in summary, `var` is referring to the same variable address. But, as `let` is blocked scope (according to the quote above), every callback in `setTimeout()` will make `i` have a different value then the previous one.

---

An experiment that is possible is to make `let` behave like `var`. To make `let` behave like `var`, you can use (and run) the code below.

*To see how `let` is behaving like `var`, read ahead about `var` hoisting!*

```js
let i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

As we moved `let` to the main scope, it behaves like `var` (as `var` is positioned at the top of the file with a value of `undefined` at runtime).

This makes the `let` variable behave like `var`, making the output of the `for` loop the same as if the `let` variable was `var`.

Thanks to [Nick Vu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71598262) for the experiment!

---

Here is a quick overview of `var` hoisting below.

The actual code (shown below):

```js
web = "stackoverflow.com";
var web;
```

Is understood as:

```js
var web;
web = "stackoverflow.com";
```

Basically, defining a variable with `var` anywhere will always result it being at the top of the file, resulting in the weird behaviour with the `for` loop.

This is why many people prefer `let` over `var`; because of how confusing [`var` hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) can be!

---

**Always use `let`, unless `var` is absolutely needed!**

Comment: your answer is very constructive, but interestingly, you copied a part of my answer without reference and mentioning :). Well, I know it's the Internet matter but sometimes you need to respect some other people's works

Comment: The confusing part for the `let` case is `i++`. This implies there is a single `i`, not an `i` one per iteration. It looks like `i++` must actually mean `next_instance_of_i = 1 + previous_instance_of_i`

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the explanation. Can we make var behave like let in this particular problem? If yes then how?

Answer (score 6):

```
for(var i=0 ;i <3 ; i++){
     setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i),1);
}
```

Js engine will examine the first for loop in the following steps :

1. i will be hoisted, to look like this :

```
    var i;
    for(i = 0 ;i < 3 ; i++){
       setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i),1);
    }
```

2. After the loop get's over , it will run setTimeOut for 3 times which will print value of **i** which is now 3

```
{ 
   i = 3 
   setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i,1);
}

{ 
   i = 3
   setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i,1);
}

{ 
   i = 3
   setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i,1);
}
```

```
for(let i=0 ;i <3 ; i++){
     setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i),1);
}
```

Js engine will examine the second for loop like this :

1. i will be hoisted, to look like this :

```
    for(let i=0 ;i < 3 ; i++){
       setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i),1);
    }
```

for the first iteration , the value of i would be 0 , and for the second iteration the value of i would be 1 and for the third it's value would be 2 .

Imagine , it as three different blocks of scope like this :

```
{ 
   i = 0 
   setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i,1);
}

{ 
   i = 1 
   setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i,1);
}

{ 
   i = 2
   setTimeOut(()=>console.log(i,1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case of `var` you are always referring to the same variable address, because `var` is function scoped.

`let` is block scoped. For every callback in setTimeout you have a different value of `i`, since it is a different block.

[Read](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

Answer (score 4):

The first loop `var i` is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#var_hoisting) and always referred to only 1 variable during that loop, `setTimeout` will postpone your `console.log` with [call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack), so that's why the value is `3` all. Here is how `var i` is constructed with hoisting under the hood.

```js
var i; //hoisted
//`var` in `for` gets removed
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

But `let i` is different, `i` value will be initialized under that block scope in iteration each time, so that's why the result is `0 1 2`.

For an experiment, to make `let` has a similar result as the `var` loop.

```js
let i; //move `i` to the upper block scope
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1); //all logs will share the same `i`
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, the setTimeout causes the log to run later, and using **var** has one instance of **i**, while using **let** has a new instance per loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the event queue in JavaScript, the setTimeout callback function is called after the loop has been executed. Since the variable i in the first loop was declared using the var keyword, this value was global. During the loop, we incremented the value of i by 1 each time, using the unary operator ++. By the time the setTimeout callback function was invoked, i was equal to 3 in the first example.

In the second loop, the variable i was declared using the let keyword: variables declared with the let (and const) keyword are block-scoped (a block is anything between { }). During each iteration, i will have a new value, and each value is scoped inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is  too lengthy  but I make sure that you get it,

In the first for `loop`, variable is declared using `‘var’` keyword. Variables declared using ‘var’ keyword are function scoped. As our first ‘for’ loop is not `enclosed` within any function, the variable is `global`, and the value of this `global variable` was `incremented` at each iteration of the first for loop. At the end of the first for loop, the variable `‘i’` will have the value of `3` as the value is `overwritten` at each iteration of the first for loop. So, at the time of execution of the first callback function from the `‘callback queue’`, the value of ‘i’ will be 3.

So, the first callback function will print numeric value 3 at console. The second and third callback function will also print the same numeric value 3 as it points the same variable.

But in the case of second for loop, we’ve used `‘let’` keyword to declare the variable. Variables declared using ‘let’ keyword are `block scoped`. A block is nothing but a pair of curly braces. So, in second for loop, a new value is used for each iteration. So, the last 3 callback functions will have the numeric values 0, 1, 2 respectively for the variable ‘i’ and hence would print 0, 1 and 2.

We can make the callback function to use the new variable value every time using ‘var’ keyword itself. As variables in javascript are function scoped (unless you use `‘let’` or `‘const’` keyword), you can call a function by passing the iteration variable. This will create a new variable every time.

Answer (score 1):

***First loop***

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

***Second loop***

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

***Solution of first loop***
Because when we declare the variable using var it will be either in global scope(when declare in global execution context) or in function scope(when declare in function execution context).So as we know in the first loop we declare the variable in the global execution context so it will have global scope. When setTimeout encounters in first loop it will give the setTimeout handler in the API's. But as we know js and time never waits for anything so js will go to next iterations and js engine will execute the for loop very fastly and when the 1s of setTimeout happens then it will push the handler functions in execution stack and ***now*** the value of i(global scope) is 3. Here the main thing is that the same i is bound to every function of setTimeout because of the concept of closures(if beginner then to understand think that i is a global variable). So console.log(i) will print 3 in each handler function of setTimeout.

***Solution of second loop***
Till ES6 developers feels very difficult because there is no block scope in javascript like other languages. So in ES6, keyword let is introduced which introduces the concept of block scope. Means the scope of variables declared using let will be only in that block(variable enclosed in the first curly braces). In some cases and generally in loops it makes more sense that variable has block scope.
***Now***, the variable i declared in second loop will have block scope of for loop. It will be available only in the one round of for loop. Now, the i is bound to every iteration of for loop. So, the new iteration will have seperate set of i here.
So, in second loop there will be 3 i which will bind to every iteration of for loop.
Now, when first iteration of for loop executes the value of i is 0 and it is bound to this iteration and setTimeout statement runs it is stored in background by javascript and will execute the function when 1s will be completed. But js waits for nobody. So next iterations of for loop will occur and in second iteration i value will be 1 bound to this iteration and so on.
When 1s happens the function of setTimeout will pushed to execution stack and each function have its i because for every iteration of for loop it has its own i which is bound to it(Here the concept of closures also come into picture).
So now every function execute of setTimeout and it will print 0,1 and 2.

***Some more info***
As told upward that i is bound to every iteration. So, when one iteration completed it will destroy. Then in next iteration how the for loop increemented 1 to the previous i. So, here the javascript actually uses var in background to maintain the for loop.
***Any doubt or suggestion, make a comment***