# How to recurring the loop to map an array values with another array values?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am working with the loop and need some help.
Actually, I have the 6 cases and want to assign them with two or three Representatives one by one. for exam :

```
caseIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Representatives = [A, B]
```

now cases should be assign like

```
1 with A, 
2 with B, 
3 with A,
4 with B, 
5 with A 
so and so.
```

what should I do?

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var ilength = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < ilength; ++i) {
  //console.log(array[i]);
  //window.alert(array[i]+ " "+s[m]);

  var s = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  var slength = s.length;
  for (var m = 0; m < slength; ++m) {
    //console.log(array[i]);
    console.log(array[i] + " " + s[m]);
  }
}
```

I tried with above code. but did not get desired output.

How can I do the same in below NetSuite suitescript?

```
function caseAssignement() {

 var filters = new Array();
 filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'anyof', 1234,9876);
 //Setting up the columns.
 var columns = new Array();
 columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');
 var searchResult = nlapiSearchRecord('recordid', null, filters, columns);
 nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'searchResult', searchResult);

 for(var i = 0; searchResult != null && i < searchResult.length; i++)
 {
   try{
 //obtain a result
 var result = searchResult[i];
   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'result', result);
 var id = result.getValue('internalid');
   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'id', id);
 var employeeid = searchEmp();
 var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('recordid',id);

     rec.setFieldValue('field_id',empid); //I want to set each employee id in the field of each record.
   nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);
   }catch (e) {
   var error = e.details || e.message || e.toString();
       nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Email error', error );
   }
 
 }
  
  }

  // Search Employee based on file name.
function searchEmp(searchResult) {
    var i_emp_id = null;
 var filters = new Array();
 filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('isinactive', null, 'is', 'F');
 filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'anyof', 2222,1111);
 var columns = new Array();
 columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');
    var o_emp_search = nlapiSearchRecord('employee_record', null, filters, columns);
    for(var i = 0; o_emp_search != null && i < o_emp_search.length; i++)
 {
 var result = o_emp_search[i];
 i_emp_id = result.getValue('internalid');
    return i_emp_id;
}

}
```

Comment: change var to let in for loop and see the result

Comment: @Nickan that won't make any difference here.

Comment: @Nickan [Explanation of `let` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this code for your scenario .
It will execute the same. You can run and check it.
Take the case id in array1 and representative record id in array2.

```
var arr1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10,11,12,13];
var arr2=["a","b"];
var k=0, j, l =arr2.length;

for(var i=k;i<arr1.length;i+k){
    
    if(arr2.length>arr1.length){
      l=  arr1.length;
    }
    for(j=0;j<l;j++){
        console.log(arr2[j]+" with "+arr1[j]);
    }
    k=j;
    arr1= arr1.slice(arr2.length);   // current sliced arr1 value

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Yogendra Chauhan, Please vote 1 for my answer it will be relevant for others as well.