# Scope of 'let' inside loop for creating closure

Tags: javascript, loops, scope, iteration, closures

I am learning Javascript Closures and I have this code

```
const functions = []

const createFunctions = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        functions.push(() => console.log(i))
}

createFunctions()

for(const func of functions) func()
```

Because of Closures, it would output:

```
0
1
2
```

That makes I think that each iteration of the for loop create a copy of i, and each function is referring to a different i. I know that let variable is block scope, and Closures are variable-oriented, not value-oriented. However we all know that if I we change the value of i inside the {} brackets, it affect the i we are using for checking conditions of the for loop, which somehow makes me think that I am using the same i for every iteration. For example:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    i++
    console.log(i)
}
```

would only output:

```
1
3
```

I would be really grateful if anyone can clarify all the concepts here

Comment: It is a different `i` for each iteration, it's just that the previous `i` value is essentially assigned to the new `i` for the new iteration.

Comment: See: [Explanation of \`let\` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612)