# Using event.target and the object itself give different results

Tags: javascript

I am creating a project where hovering on buttons on a 16x16 grid of buttons turns them red(etch-a-sketch)

Here for changing colors, I tried:

```
const cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));

for(i of cells){
    i.addEventListener("mouseover",function(event){
        i.style.background = "red";
    });
}
```

But it didn't work as intended and only changed the color of the last button in the array when hovering on any of the buttons. But the following worked:

```
const cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));

for(i of cells){
    i.addEventListener("mouseover",function(event){
        event.target.style.background = "red";
    });
}
```

What exactly is the difference between these two? Because I assumed `event.target` would refer to `i` so both pieces of code would do the same thing.

Comment: Relevant: [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Comment: In your first example `i` is updated in every iteration of the loop. Therefore when the event fires `i` will hold the *last* value it was set to, ie. the last element in the `cells` array. When you read the `event.target` you are explicitly accessing the element that raised the event in the DOM

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486)

Comment: @NickParsons The post you linked says that if `let` is used, a new variable with loop scope. Does that mean that in JS, the loop variables exist even after the loop runs to completion (i.e it is terminated)? Because other answers have pointed out that `i` will refer to the last button after completion of the loop.

Comment: @FirstTree - when you use `let` JavaScript will create a new version of your `i` variable for each iteration. These variables only exist in your case as the functions that you create in your loop refer to them (so they can’t be garbage collected as code still refers to it). When you don’t use `let` and use `var` instead, or don’t use anything, then only one `i` variable is created (in the scope of where your loop is, such as if you declared i before the loop), and so that `i` is reused for each iteration and updated.

Comment: You can see this question for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899612/explanation-of-let-and-block-scoping-with-for-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example `i` is updated in every iteration of the loop. Therefore when the event fires `i` will hold the *last* value it was set to, ie. the last element in the `cells` array. When you read the `event.target` you are explicitly accessing the element that raised the event in the DOM. It's for this reason that the latter approach is by far the better method.

Also note that your code can be made more succinct. You can use `forEach()` directly on the Collection returned by `querySelectorAll()` without needing to maintain any indexer variable:

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");

cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener("mouseover", e => e.target.style.background = "red"));
```

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
}

.container .cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rory McCrossan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78012258/58186) explains why the different code snippet results differ.

I would add the suggestion to use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) instead of assigning a handler to every element.

```js
document.addEventListener(`mouseover`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const originCell = evt.target.closest(`.cell`);
  
  if (originCell) {
    if (evt.type === `click`) { /* 'undo' */
      return originCell.classList.remove(`red`);
    }
    
    return originCell.classList.add(`red`);
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
.container .cell.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
}

.container .cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```