# Use IIFE in setTimeout in a loop, but why?

Tags: javascript

I know it is a classic js question:

(My question is not how to solve this problem, but how IIFE solve this problem. Thanks for the other answer link but I didn't find the answer I want)

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    },1000)
}
```

This will print out five consecutive 5, and one way to avoid that is to create IIFE in setTimeout, I know it creates a closure but still why? Can someone give a more specific explanation about it?

Also why can't I just pass a parameter to the function?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(i) {
        console.log(i);
    },1000)
}
```

This prints out 5 undefined...I got more confused, why is that?

Comment: @Paulpro Genuinely curios, how should we answer the second part of OP's question when it has been closed as a duplicate because of the first part of his question?

Comment: @le_m The dupe answers both parts.

Comment: @le_m Nevermind, I see the distinction now.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to print 0...4. You can achieve that by using `let` instead of `var` which creates a new binding of `i` for each loop iteration [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473350/let-keyword-in-the-for-loop), [[2]](http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html#let-in-loop-heads):

```js
// Prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Your suggestion to add an argument `i` to the callback fails as the calling function `setTimeout` doesn't pass anything to the callback. Thus the `i` argument is undefined.

Alternatively, use the [classic IIFE approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        }, 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

Even better, of course, would be to move the for-loop into the `setTimeout` callback. But I assume you chose this code for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: Thank you for the "let" solution, but I wonder how IIFE solves this problem?

Comment: @KemingZeng This answer to the linked question has a good intuitive explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299889/1647737

Comment: I see, so the key is that IIFE immediately pass the parameter "i" before setTimeout is pushed to the execution queue? But I still don't know why the second one logs undefined

Comment: I see your point, in your code, you create an IIFE outside the settimeout function and pass "i" immediately to the anonymous callback function. But if I create an IIFE inside settimeout, make the anonymous function IIFE, it still works, then why is that?

Comment: The IIFE is evaluated immediately during each loop-iteration. When evaluating the IIFE, JavaScript binds the IIFE's `i` argument to the **value** (i.e. 1, 2, ...) of the loop-iterator variable `i`. The setTimeout callback is a closure with access to this 'inner' `i`. Now, regarding your `setTimeout(function(i) ...` - this `i` is an argument of the callback. However, setTimeout calls your callback without providing any arguments, i.e. it calls `callback()`. Now, if you call a `function (a) { ...}` without supplying any arguments, then `a` is undefined. This is what happens here to `i`.

Comment: Than you for your explanation!

Comment: @le_m  Can you please explain what do you mean by "Even better, of course, would be to move the for-loop into the setTimeout callback."