# Unexpected behavior: Javascript, setTimeout(), and IIFE

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout, iife

**Javascript, Event loop, setTimeout, IIFE, closure**

Based on references below, my understanding of the following code is:

setTimeout() is non-blocking and handled by the Browser Web APIs, which put the callbacks on the callback queue when the timer is done. Then the event loop waits for the call stack to be free to run each callback in turn. setTimeout closure closes over the anonymous IIFE and has the correct value of index for each iteration.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    (function(index){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(index);
        }, 5000);
    })(i);
    console.log("loop="+i);
}
/*Output in console is
loop=0
loop=1
loop=2
//after 5 seconds
0
1
2
*/
```

I'm looking for an explanation of what's happening with the following code in Chrome.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(
        function(index) { 
            console.log(index);
        }(i), 5000
    );
    console.log("loop="+i);
}
/* Output in console without any delay is:
0
loop=0
1
loop=1
2
loop=2
*/
```

Why is 'console.log(index)' executed immediately, without a 5 second delay?

How does the web API execute setTimeout() with a callback as an IIFE?

Are any callbacks put in the callback queue?

Does the event loop move any callbacks to the call stack?

Or is setTimeout() being ignored and its callback being executed immediately on the call stack?

---

References I've consulted:

Philip Roberts: What the heck is the event loop anyway? | JSConf EU 2014
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Philip Roberts Help I'm stuck in an event loop 2016
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MXRNXXgP_0

Call Stack & Event Loop
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk0lu9MKBto

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

[Use IIFE in setTimeout in a loop, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059359/use-iife-in-settimeout-in-a-loop-but-why)

Comment: As a side note, if you want to pass arguments to setTimeout, you need to put them after the delay argument, e.g. setTimeout(function (index) { /* do stuff */ }, 5000, i);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
setTimeout(
    function(index) { 
        console.log(index);
    }(i), 5000
);
```

You're invoking the first argument passed to `setTimeout` *immediately*. When the interpreter comes across the `setTimeout` line, it first tries to resolve all of its arguments to values. The first argument is a function invocation, so it invokes that function in the expectation that it will resolve to *another* function - just like how one could do

```
setTimeout(makeFn('foo'), 5000);
```

where `makeFn` returns a function.

So, in your code, the

```
    function(index) { 
        console.log(index);
    }(i)
```

runs immediately, but it doesn't return anything - the interpreter resolves the `setTimeout` line to

```
setTimeout(undefined, 5000);
```

but `undefined` isn't a function, so nothing asynchronous gets queued up.

You don't have any IIFEs here - put the whole `setTimeout` line in an IIFE instead:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ((i) => {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        console.log(i);
      }, 500
    );
    console.log("loop=" + i);
  })(i);
}
```

(or, of course, use `const` or `let` instead of `var` - best to avoid `var`, its hoisting and function scope is very unintuitive and requires verbose workarounds like these in `for` loops)

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      console.log(i);
    }, 500
  );
  console.log("loop=" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In second example you are not passing the function to the `setTimeout` but you rather passing it's result of the function call (in this case it's void).

```
        function(index) { 
            console.log(index);
        }(i)
```

you see, in this example your function invokes immediately thus, there's nothing to call later, and console logs in order.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for an explanation of what's happening with the following
>   code in Chrome.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(
        function(index) { 
            console.log(index);
        }(i), 5000
    );
    console.log("loop="+i);
}
/* Output in console without any delay is:
0
loop=0
1
loop=1
2
loop=2
*/
```

Consider the following statement:

```
function(index) { 
    console.log(index);
}(i)
```

This is an *anonymous function* and executed immediately (the parentheses '()' at the end executes the function): see the syntax `function(param) {...}()`. So the effect is that for each iteration the above code is executed immediately.

The result is (as you see it):

```
0
1
2
```

The [setTimeout at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). method expects a *function* (to be executed *after* the timer expires) or *code* as its first parameter. In this case you have code (not a function) that executes immediately. So, you see the result immediately.

The delay of 5 seconds has no effect, its never used. There is nothing to execute after the delay.

The effect is same in Firefox too.

You can try the code without the parentheses at the end of the anonymous function and see what happens:

```
function(index) { 
    console.log(index);
}
```

The function will execute after the delay of five seconds, in this case!