# Trouble with refering to a variable in mouseover event

Tags: javascript, events, nested

I want to make an event where .gridss change colors with mouseover event. Problem is gridss comes out as not definied,and if i try to move the mouseover event into the the gridss function it also does not work. So how can I successfully refer to .gridds?

My question is pretty simple yet i cant seem to get it right,so thanks in advance.

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            let gridss = $("<div class='gridss'></div>");
            gridss.appendTo('#container');
        }
    }
});

gridss.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ){
  event.target.style.color = "purple";

  setTimeout(function(){
    event.target.style.color = "";
  }, 10);
}, false);
```

Comment: What's the timeout for? Did you want the text to revert back to initial color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery for events if you are using jQuery. I assume that you are not aware of `mouseout` or `mouseleave` because it looks like you are using `setTimeout()` to trigger a delay of text color reverting back to original color. I used [**`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` which are similar to `mouseover` and `mouseout` events**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104403/2813224).

You had an error which that `gridss` wasn't defined. The reason why moving in and out of functions didn't work is because you defined `gridss` with `let`.

- `let` is limited scope to that of the block
- `var` scope is the function which works as long as you have `gridss` in the function.

#### Demo

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
    var gridss = $("<div class='gridss'>TEST</div>");
    gridss.appendTo('#container');
  }
  $('.gridss').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
      this.style.color = "purple";
    } else {
      this.style.color = "white";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 5px solid blue
}

.gridss {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: cyan;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  transition: color .5s ease
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ohh okay that makes sense, but now event (line 12) shows up as undefined, why is that?

Comment: Are you using Firefox? I'm using Chrome and saw no error. See Update it may answer your question

Comment: Why are you using 2 for`s?

Comment: @CataJohn OP's code it's not efficient but it's not the problem.

Comment: @zer00ne ok, right. Anyway, your solution works for me.

Comment: @CataJohn I removed one of the loops and doubled the 2nd parameter and added `let` to the first parameter [a good use of `let` is using it in loops to declare initial value of an increment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812376/2813224)

Comment: @zer00ne nice. Const can also be used here as 'y' is never reassigned a value. Const also creates a lexical scope for each iteration, same as let.

Comment: @CataJohn I cannot touch `const` because when I see it I associate it with C and C++ then I get a headache. Same with `class`  :/