# Does array.push copies deeply?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make array of workers so I wrote this code.

```
for(var c=0;c<core;c++){
let worker = new Worker("Html/Worker.js");
worker.postMessage({core:core,W:width,H:height,id:c,px:px,py:py,pz:pz,yaw:yaw,pitch:pitch,D:D,fov:fov});
worker.onmessage=(e)=>{
let gap = this.sH/core*e.data[2];
this.frameBuffer.set(e.data[0],Math.floor(gap)*this.sW*4);
//alert(e.data);
this.depthBuffer.set(e.data[1],Math.floor(gap)*this.sW);
}
this.threads.push(worker);
}
```

I wonder if it's able to copy worker without multiple initialization (like the code below)

```
let worker = new Worker("Html/Worker.js");
for(var c=0;c<core;c++){
worker.postMessage({core:core,W:width,H:height,id:c,px:px,py:py,pz:pz,yaw:yaw,pitch:pitch,D:D,fov:fov});
worker.onmessage=(e)=>{
let gap = this.sH/core*e.data[2];
this.frameBuffer.set(e.data[0],Math.floor(gap)*this.sW*4);
this.depthBuffer.set(e.data[1],Math.floor(gap)*this.sW);
}
this.threads.push(worker);
}
```

does array.push causes deep copying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `Array.push` does not cause deep copying.

`this.threads.push(worker)` will not modify the `worker` you are passing to it but will just add it as-is to the array `this.threads`.

This means in your second example there will be only one worker which receives `core` many messages and have a single message listener.

Please notice that in both examples you should not access `c` in your `onmessage` callback because at the time of receiving messages `c` will be equal to `core`.
If you need it in the callback, declare it with `let c` instead of `var c` to have access to *the value at the time of creating the callback* ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473350/let-keyword-in-the-for-loop)).