# JS: Variable scopes and event-loop

Tags: javascript, events, scope

I'd like to understand the following code:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
console.log('After the Loop');
```

Prints `After the loop,3,3,3`

```
for (let i=0; i<3; i++){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
console.log('After the Loop');
```

Prints `After the loop,0,1,2`

I know that the events are executed after the `main`, so the numbers of `i` appear after `After the loop`. And `let`means block scope (so `i`is visible in `for`-loop only) and `var`function scope (so it should be visible globally here), but I still don't see why the first prints `3,3,3`.

Can anyone please provide a resonable explaination?

Thanks!

Comment: In the first example there is only a single variable `i` and all functions refer to that. A single variable can only have a single value at a time.

Comment: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/691711) and [let keyword in the for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812376/691711)

Comment: Got it :-) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `var`, the same `i` is shared by all the anonymous functions passed to `setTimeout()`. The timeouts fire a relatively long time after the loop finishes, so by that time the value of the (shared) `i` is 3.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following examples which show `i` defined using `var` and `let` and how scope is determined at the function and block level.

```
// "i" defined with "var" within the function scope
function foo() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => console.log('foo', i), 250);
    }
    // output: 3 3 3
}

// "i" defined with "let" within the function scope
function bar() {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => console.log('bar', i), 250);
    }
    // output: 3 3 3
}

// "i" is defined within the block however it gets hoisted up
// to the function scope as this is the behavior of "var"
function baz() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => console.log('baz', i), 250);
    }
    // output: 3 3 3
}

// "i" is defined within the block and "let" allows "i" to maintain the block scope
function boo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => console.log('boo', i), 250);
    }
    // output: 0 1 2
}
```