# Why am I able to initialize and assign the variable again inside the for loop using 'let'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i); //outputs 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

**HERE ↓ IS THE DOUBT**

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let i = 2;
    console.log(i); //output 2 five times
}
```

Why am I able to initialize and assign the `i` variable twice, as I know we can only initialize and assign the variable declared with `let` once and later can reassign it another value. For example:

```
let j = 5;
let j = 6;
console.log(j); //error > Identifier 'i' has already been declared

let k = 5;
k = 6;
console.log(k); // output 6
```

Comment: inside the for loop, the let created scope only for one time, and update the value. it doesnt create let variable again and again. So assiging to same mutable var is ok. However, the second case is not true.

Comment: This is an interesting question because the `let i` from the `for` loop declaration is kept separate for each invocation of the loop, but is apparently not a full-fledged `let i` inside the `for` loop, otherwise it would conflict with the redefinition and be an error.  It must have to do with the "special" treatment that the `for` loop variable gets.  It would be interesting to see the actual ECMAScript reference that explains how the `for` loop `let i` works.

Answer (score 2):

It's like the form of:

```
let j = 5;
{
  let j = 6;
  console.log(j); //6
}
console.log(j); //5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let i = 2;
    console.log(i); //output 2 five times
}
```

In second line, just because {} brackets. You are crating a new scope. For more please go through [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

```
let j = 5;
let j = 6;
console.log(j);
```

Here no scope diffrence, so error.

```
let k = 5;
k = 6;
console.log(k);
```

Here both k are in same scope. and you are re-assigning value.

Answer (score 1):

The `let`declaration keeps the variable only within the scope. How Javascript handles scope for for iterative loop is that a new scope is started every iteration. The `var` keyword will leak the variable into the global scope and maintained every iteration, whereas the `let` will allow a new `i` to be declared. For more details, here's a Babel compiled javascript which we can see the actual variables being used and understand this scoping anomaly better! https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367144/8181001