# Value not assigning in for function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running a for function which dynamically creates elements based on an entered number. I have an event listener for when the div is clicked.

This is the function that I am using to make these buttons.

```
function createGame(value) {
  previousNo = value;
  for (i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    gameCircle = document.createElement("div");
    gameCircle.className = 'gameCircle';
    gameCircle.id = "circle" + i;
    gameCircle.onclick = function() {
      checkGame(i);
    };
    document.getElementById("circleGame").appendChild(gameCircle);
  }
}
```

And this is the function I am calling.

```
function checkGame(j) {
  var nextNo = circleArr.shift();
  if (j == nextNo) {
    document.getElementById("circle" + i).style.backgroundColor = "#178a00";
  } else {
    console.log(j);
    getValueGame();
  }
}
```

Everytime the function runs, it returns six. Additionally, checking the onclick listener assigned says it runs this function.

```
function () {
  checkGame(i);
}
```

Why does the function return six on every button, and why is the i value not being assigned to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of chronology. Think about it; the event callback is not executed until later, by which time the value of `i` is, and has remained since the loop finished, a number equal to whatever `value` was.

The simplest way to resolve this is to use `let` for your iteration variable rather than `var` (this is good practice for variables these days in JavaScript generally, not just in your case.)

`let` "locks in" the value of `i` for each closure encountered in your loop. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812376/1352288) discusses this in more detail.

You can achieve the same result by passing a `var`-declared iteration variable into the callback scope via an immediately-executed function expression (IIFE).

```
gameCircle.onclick = (i => () => checkGame(i))(i);
```

Or, in more readable terms:

```
gameCircle.onclick = (function(i) {
    return function() { checkGame(i); };
})(i)
```

Answer (score -2):

document.getElementById("circle" + i).style.backgroundColor = "#178a00";

i is not defined inside your function i think use j instead  i

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.