# Adding element to existing object in an array results in the TypeError: Cannot set property 'live' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I am trying to push a new property value into the existing JSONArray but when I do that I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'live' of undefined`.

```
var ProxyData       =   [];

//Setting some of the fields outside the for loop
ProxyData.push({
                    'country'       :   country,
                    'ip'            :   ip,
                    'port'          :   port,
                    'createdAt'     :   createdAt,
                    'updatedAt'     :   updatedAt,
                    'provider'      :   'proxy11.com'
                });

//Based on some value I need to add thie live field
for(var item=0; item<ProxyData.length; item++)
{
    ProxyData[item].live    =   'Yes';

}
```

I want to retain the previously set objects but along with this based on some condition within the for loop I want to add the new field `live` to an object in the array. How can I achieve that?

I tried this also but no luck:
`ProxyData[item]["live"] = "Yes";`

I tried defining the `live` field before so that I can set it later but still its not working:

```
ProxyData.push({
                            'country'       :   country,
                            'ip'            :   ip,
                            'port'          :   port,
                            'createdAt'     :   createdAt,
                            'updatedAt'     :   updatedAt,
                            'provider'      :   'proxy11.com',
                            'live'          :   ''
                        });
```

I posted the above code for simple understanding but to make it clear I will post the complete code from my project:

```
var ProxyData       =   [];

for(var itemCount=0; itemCount<pageData.data.length; itemCount++)
{
    var country     =   pageData.data[itemCount].country;
    var ip          =   pageData.data[itemCount].ip;
    var port        =   pageData.data[itemCount].port;
    var createdAt   =   pageData.data[itemCount].createdAt;
    var updatedAt   =   pageData.data[itemCount].updatedAt;

    ProxyData.push({
        'country'       :   country,
        'ip'            :   ip,
        'port'          :   port,
        'createdAt'     :   createdAt,
        'updatedAt'     :   updatedAt,
        'provider'      :   'proxy11.com'
    });

    itemProcessed++;

    if(itemProcessed == pageData.data.length)
    {

        var     sql     =   " INSERT INTO TBL_PROXY (IP, COUNTRY, PORT, CREATED_DT_TM, UPDATE_DT_TM, PROVIDER) VALUES ";

        for(var item=0; item<ProxyData.length; item++)
        {
            var proxy       =   'http://'+ProxyData[item].ip+':'+ProxyData[item].port;
            var liveState   =   "";

            request({
                'url':'localhost:3000',
                'method': "GET",
                'proxy': proxy
            },function (error, response, body) {

                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    ProxyData[item].live    =   'Yes';
                    console.log(ProxyData);
                }
                else
                {
                    ProxyData[item].live    =   'No';
                    console.log(ProxyData);
                }
            });

            sql         +=  util.format(" (%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ", ProxyData[item].ip, ProxyData[item].country, ProxyData[item].port, ProxyData[item].createdAt, ProxyData[item].updatedAt, ProxyData[item].provider)+',';
        }



        sql     =   sql.slice(0, sql.length-1);

        db.Proxy_Feed_Data_Push(sql, function(data){
            callback(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can store your json as object  `let ProxyData = {...} `and then add whatever property you want `ProxyData.live = "yes"`

Comment: Before the for loop I have another for loop which is initially populating the `ProxyData`. I have modified the code here so that it would be easy to answer. I have tried this before and it has worked but for some reason I am able to make it work now.

Comment: The code works as it is. Log `item` to the console before trying to use it.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I try to continue further. If I remove the `ProxyData[item]["live"] = "Yes";` everything works fine. Not sure what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By the time your asynchronous call has finished, the value of "`item`" has changed.  Try adding `console.log(item, ProxyData[item]);` after `function (error, response, body) {` to see.

Another way of seeing this phenomenon is with this simple example:

```
var ProxyData = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var item = 0; item < ProxyData.length; item++) {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(item, ProxyData[item]);
  });
}
// Results in:
// 3 undefined
// 3 undefined
// 3 undefined
```

In [modern JavaScript environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812376), simply using `let` rather than `var` fixes this issue.

Since `var` is scoped to the function (not block) it is defined in, one workaround would be to (1) wrap every loop iteration with a function and (2) define a new variable (3) with the value of `item` so that when the synchronous call finishes, it uses the correct especially-defined-for-it variable.

```
    for(var item=0; item<ProxyData.length; item++)
    {
        // (1) wrap in a IIFE
        // (2) define a new variable
        (function(item2) {

            var proxy       =   'http://'+ProxyData[item].ip+':'+ProxyData[item].port;
            var liveState   =   "";

            request({
                'url':'localhost:3000',
                'method': "GET",
                'proxy': proxy
            },function (error, response, body) {
                // Even though 'item' has changed by now,
                // the variable 'item2' is scoped to the function
                // inside the loop iteration so it's what you expect.

                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    ProxyData[item2].live    =   'Yes';
                    console.log(ProxyData);
                }
                else
                {
                    ProxyData[item2].live    =   'No';
                    console.log(ProxyData);
                }
            });

            sql         +=  util.format(" (%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ", ProxyData[item].ip, ProxyData[item].country, ProxyData[item].port, ProxyData[item].createdAt, ProxyData[item].updatedAt, ProxyData[item].provider)+',';

        // (3) pass the value of 'item', it'll be assigned to 'item2'
        })(item);
    }
```

You *could* name the `item2` variable `item`, but that could be confusing.

Or just use block-scoped variables in place of defining a function:

```
    let item2 = item;
    // When you run your async call later, it'll have
    // the correct value because 'let' is scoped to the 
    // nearest block (which is 'for() {}').
```