# How new unique "i" is created by let keyword in for loop?

Tags: javascript

In the following code [example](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/thrown-for-a-loop-understanding-for-loops-and-timeouts-in-javascript-558d8255d8a4/#:%7E:text=The%20second%20thing%20let%20does%20for%20us%20is%20create%20a%20unique%20value%20of%20i%20each%20time%20the%20loop%20iterates.%20When%20our%20loop%20is%20over%2C%20we%20have%20created%20six%20separate%20values%20of%20i%20that%20are%20stored%20in%20memory%20that%20our%20console.log(i)%20statements%20can%20access.%20With%20var%2C%20we%20only%20had%20one%20variable%20that%20we%20kept%20overwriting)  writes

> `let` does for us is create a unique value of `i` each time the loop iterates. When our loop is over, we have created six separate values of `i` that are stored in memory that our `console.log(i)` statements can access."

How `let` create a new `i` in every iteration but only one `var i`?

Comment: FYI [tag:basic] is about the BASIC programming language, not basic/beginner questions.

Comment: Please add all the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: `example` is a web page - please post the code you are referring to instead of a link to a webpage

Comment: `let` doesn't create a `var`-- `let` _is_ a type of variable/container-- but unlike a `const` it can be reassigned to a different value, which it is at every iteration of the loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812376/10549313